# nant directory::exists returns false even though directory exists

Tags: nant

I'm trying to check for if a directory exists as part of a NAnt script and getting a false negative.  Here is the script fragment:

```
<echo message="${backup.dir} --> ${directory::exists('${backup.dir}')}"/>
```

Here is the output:

```
[echo] D:\D\RTC\backup\20110223 --> False
```

Except the directory exists.

As a side note if I run..

```
<echo message="${backup.dir} --> ${directory::get-creation-time('${backup.dir}')}"/>
```

I get the following error:

```
Expression: ${backup.dir} --> ${directory::get-creation-time('${backup.dir}')}
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Could not find a part of the path "D:\D\RTC\${backup.dir}".
```

AND if I run..

```
<echo message="Directory Name --> ${path::get-directory-name('${backup.dir}')}"/>
```

I get

```
[echo] Directory Name -->
```

All in all I'm very confused right now.. Any thoughts?

Comment: Removing the \backup\ piece as well as switching to / had no effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must not use `${}` in a nested way:

```
<echo message="${backup.dir} --> ${directory::exists(backup.dir)}"/>
```

Comment: Also forgot this ... I made this mistake in several build scripts which I have to adjust now ... There should be a NAnt warning when using nested ${} anyway ;-)